# JPA can not load Entity becuase it can not find an instance of it with columnname present in entity and saving works

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I am using eclipselink as JPA and I have this Problem:
The entity i do save is not found right after saving when I try to load it with the entity manager

I have following classes:
User.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements DbObject {

   @Transient
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false)
   private long id;
   @Column(nullable = false)
   private String password;
   @ManyToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "users_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "roles_id"))
   private Set<Role> roles;
   @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true, updatable = false)
   private String username;

   public User() {
   }

   public User(long id, String username, String password, Set<Role> roles) {
      this.id = id;
      this.username = username;
      this.password = password;
      this.roles = roles;
   }

   @Override
   public Object clone() {
      return id == 0 && StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(username) && StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(password) && roles.isEmpty()
            ? new User()
            : new User(id, username, password, roles);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      if (o == this) {
         return true;
      }
      if (o instanceof User) {
         final User u = (User) o;
         // only check name, since role names should be unique across an entire
         // application:
         return getUsername() != null ? getUsername().equals(u.getUsername()) : u.getUsername() == null;
      }
      return false;
   }

   @Override
   public long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public String getPassword() {
      return password;
   }

   public Set<Role> getRoles() {
      return roles;
   }

   public String getUsername() {
      return username;
   }

   @Override
   public int hashCode() {
      return getUsername() != null ? getUsername().hashCode() : 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public void setPassword(String password) {
      this.password = password;
   }

   public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
      this.roles = roles;
   }

   public void setUsername(String username) {
      this.username = username;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return getUsername();
   }

}
```

with A Service which tries to load the Entity by column name
UserService.java

```
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

   private final UserRepository userRepository;

   @Inject
   public UserServiceImpl(final UserRepository userRepository) {
      this.userRepository = userRepository;
   }

   @Override
   public Optional<User> findByName(final String username) {
      return userRepository.findByColumnValue("username", username).stream().findAny();
   }

   @Override
   public AbstractJpaRepository<User, Long> getRepository() {
      return userRepository;
   }

}
```

and a UserRepository extending this AbstractJpaRepository interface:

```
public interface AbstractJpaRepository<T, ID> {

   default void delete(ID id) {
      final EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
      final T toBeRemoved = entityManager.getReference(getType(), id);
      entityManager.remove(toBeRemoved);
   }

   default ObservableList<T> findAll() {
      final EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();

      final CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(getType());
      criteriaQuery.from(getType());

      final ObservableList<T> list = FXCollections
            .observableArrayList(entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList());
      return list;
   }

   default List<T> findByColumnValue(final String columnHeader, final String columnValue) {
      final EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
      final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

      final CriteriaQuery<T> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(getType());

      final Root<T> from = criteriaQuery.from(getType());

      criteriaQuery.select(from);
      criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(from.get(columnHeader), columnValue));

      final TypedQuery<T> typed = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
      return typed.getResultStream().collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   default Optional<T> findById(final ID id) {
      final EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
      return Optional.ofNullable(entityManager.find(getType(), id));
   }

   EntityManager getEntityManager();

   Class<T> getType();

   default T save(final T t) {
      final EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
      for (final DatabaseField dbf : entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getDescriptor(User.class).getFields()) {
         System.out.println(dbf.getName());
      }
      return entityManager.merge(t);
   }

}
```

As you can see I iterate over the DatabaseFields of the entity and there the expected columnname is present. But when I try to load an User Entity by the Columnname username it does not find the expected entity, which I save just before. When I assign an entity to the return object of the save it seems like everything worked so I assume there is no Problem there. Does anyone know of eclipselink since the jakarta update if it has a bug? since I updated my poms versions in this project and I have a this new project which I set up just alike juts with an outdated eclipselink version, which has ciritical vulnaerabilities. You can clone the whole project at https://github.com/mitvitaminen/crowear_hp to have the whole source code which I expect to be too much for this post to actually be of help. Checkout the testdataserviceimpl where I create a user with username testUser1 and testUser1 as PW so you can try out to login but it throws an exception since the entity User with testUser1 as username is not found.

I iterated like this when saving

```
for (final DatabaseField dbf : entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getDescriptor(User.class).getFields()) {
         System.out.println(dbf.getName());
      }
```

where the correct column name is displayed. But when I try to get the entity back from the db it just wont load and an empty optional is returned.

Any help appreciated

Kind regards Chris

Comment: What happens if you search by ID? How are you sure that your entity is actually saved - did you check the database directly? Could it be the transaction isn't committed, or you are not in a transaction? Try turning on EclipseLink SQL logging and see what is generated for your findbyName query to see that it matches what you expect on the DB.

Comment: I had an error in my config nevermind